# Numbering of floats in \chapter*

Tags: floats, numbering, koma-script

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,listof=leveldown]{scrbook}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\begin{document}
\listoflistings
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter*{Introduction}
%
\begin{listing}
    \caption{My first listing.}
\end{listing}
%
\begin{figure}
    \caption{My first figure.}
\end{figure}
%
\begin{table}
    \caption{My first table.}
\end{table}

\chapter{Another chapter}
%
\begin{listing}
    \caption{My second listing.}
\end{listing}
%
\begin{figure}
    \caption{My second figure.}
\end{figure}
%
\begin{table}
    \caption{My second table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

How can I have figures and tables be numbered `1`, `2` etc. in `\chapter*` and `1.1`, `1.2` etc. in `\chapter` 1?

Loading `minted` with the option `newfloat` numbers the listings as desired. Loading it without `newfloat` and the listings also behaves like the figures and tables.

Comment: well you can do it by redefining `\thefigure`, but imho this is a rather confusing numbering. Why don't you simple number the chapter to get a consistent numbering?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I used `\chapter*{Introduction}` because I thought the introduction would not be numbered. Maybe I'm wrong here and this question is actually the very definition of an XY-problem ... :)

Comment: \chapter does four things: it increments the chapter counter, it adds an entry for the TOC, it changes the header, and it prints the title.  \chapter* only prints the title (no chapter number).  If you want it to do more, you need to add the extra steps yourself.

Comment: You could use `\frontmatter\chapter{Introduction} ... \mainmatter`. But note, the page numbers in front matter are `roman`.

Comment: Or you could install a [pre-release](https://komascript.de/current) of KOMA-Script version 3.35. See [Known issues and important changes in KOMA-Script 3.35](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/Release%203.35/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it is not good solution for You couse I changed `\documentclass`, but look like it wokrs(if it useless tell, wil be deleted):
[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,listof=leveldown]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}


\begin{document}

\let\LaTeXStandardClearpage\clearpage
\let\clearpage\relax  % Do nothing when a \clearpage command appears 
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
\let\clearpage\LaTeXStandardClearpage % Return to the old definition

\chapter*{Introduction}
%
\begin{listing}
\caption{My first listing.}
\end{listing}
%
\begin{figure}
\caption{My first figure.}
\end{figure}
%
\begin{table}
\caption{My first table.}
\end{table}

\chapter{Another chapter}
%
\begin{listing}
\caption{My second listing.}
\end{listing}
%
\begin{figure}
\caption{My second figure.}
\end{figure}
%
\begin{table}
\caption{My second table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```